# Processes of creating a 3D avatar editor for users?

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit

I'd like to provide users with the ability to edit the shape, form and properties of their 3D character from templates.

What are the general processes and delineations of responsibility when targeting iOS and using Xcode, Swift, Scene Kit and a 3D modelling application?

Comment: You can use Objective-C libraries in Swift…

Comment: thanks for the fast answer  can i use this to make this editable avatar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in anything 3D related but I believe I can help in this case.

iOS has a 3D engine called SceneKit, you can programmatically create basic 3D objects.

For complex objects you usually create them in an external program such as Cheetah3D and then you can import them and interact with the object in SceneKit.

Some references you may find useful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework

http://www.cheetah3d.com/

http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/08/10/import-cheetah3d-model-in-scenekit

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83748/beginning-scene-kit-tutorial

The Ray Wenderlich site has been a great resource for me learning iOS, they have alot of tutorials, video tutorials and even ebooks that you can purchase on a number of topics including game development with iOS and Unity.

Comment: thx alot but just to make sure that i understand right  can it allow the user to edit it in the app or just put the avatar there? it's say here (SceneKit[1] is a high-level 3D framework, introduced in Mountain Lion, that allows reading, manipulating and displaying 3D scenes.) so i  take this as a yes right ,thanks for your help ^^

Comment: I know that you can interact with the models, animate and move them, not too sure if you can change certain aspects of it though, like increase the size of a certain part. you may need to combine a number of smaller models to create the actual final character

Comment: thanks for your help,there mush be away to edit the size in xcode ,i though o your idea but i'm afraid that it will miss the avatar look , i will keep searching on how to make the avatar change size in ios ^^